# Subset zoo time series object for a specific month

Tags: r

I have following dataset(dailyData):

```
Date       V1   V2 V3
08/01/13    20  9   3 
08/02/13    21  9   4 
08/03/13    21  10  3 
08/04/13    25  7   4 
08/05/13    22  7   5 
08/06/13    23  8   3 
08/07/13    20  9   3 
08/08/13    24  8   4 
08/09/13    26  9   5 
09/01/13    18  9   7
```

I create a time series by converting to a zoo object as follows:

```
require("zoo")
myts <- zoo(x = dailyData[2:4], order.by = dailyData$Date, frequency = 1)
```

what I want to do is to Subset data by month in R or subset a month for this zoo object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `myts[format(index(myts), "%m")=="08"]` for August data?

Comment: Try the `months()` function from base R